# Do too many generic types in class mean bad design?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that takes *three* generic type arguments. I was wondering if that is good to do. I mean is this considered as design smell? Suppose some class has even more then what is an approximate limit to the number of generic arguments?

```
class InnerStateMachine<ST extends Enum<?>,EV extends Enum<?>,PEV extends Enum<?>>{

}
```

Where

`ST` - are the states of inner state machine

`EV` - are events of inner state machine

`PEV` - are the events of parent state machine that I use for communication between state machines

***UPDATE**:* The inner state machine is contained with another state machine which is the parent. So if inner state machine wants to fire some event on parent then it does so using one of `PEV` events which then parent uses to do some transition and change its state and perform some action.

Comment: You might consider replacing generics with interfaces, if possible.

Comment: But I also need to ensure that arguments are an Enum. Is this achievable with interface then?

Comment: that totally depends on the kind of problem you are solving..unless you provide us with your exact problem,we would not be able to help you with your question!

Comment: do you have different sets of the st, ev, and pev enums or is there just one set of each?

Comment: @RayTayek they are different as all represent events and states.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain some context, tell me if you want some more details.

Comment: Is there more that one set of ParentEvents?

Comment: The question is tautological. You're already said 'too many'. Too much of anything is too much.

Comment: @EJP I just asked as I was thinking whether there is such rule as to how many maximum generic type arguments should be used and more than that indicates some design issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the code below. It's a little ugly to initialize the inner state machines though.

edit: add generic parent event.

```
import java.util.*;
interface Event {}
enum AEvent implements Event {
    e1
}
enum BEvent implements Event {
    e1
}
interface State {
    State processEvent(Event event);
}
enum AState implements State {
    s1,s2;
    public State processEvent(Event event) {
        return eventToState.get(event);
    }
    final Map<Event,State> eventToState=new TreeMap<Event,State>();
}
enum BState implements State {
    s1,s2;
    public State processEvent(Event event) {
        return eventToState.get(event);
    }
    final Map<Event,State> eventToState=new TreeMap<Event,State>();
}
interface ParentEvent {}
enum ParentEvents implements ParentEvent {
    e1;
}
class InnerStateMachine<St extends Enum<?> &State,Ev extends Enum<?> &Event,PEV extends Enum<?> &ParentEvent> {
    public InnerStateMachine(St state) {
        this.state=state;
    }
    St state() {
        return state;
    }
    St processEvent(Ev event) {
        State s=state.processEvent(event);
        if(s instanceof Enum<?>) {
            PEV pev=stateToParentEvent.get(s);
            if(pev!=null)
                System.out.println("fire parent event "+pev);
            return state=(St)s; // unsafe cast
        } else throw new RuntimeException("oops");
    }
    St state;
    Map<St,PEV> stateToParentEvent=new TreeMap<St,PEV>();
}
public class So15804185 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AState.s1.eventToState.put(AEvent.e1,AState.s2);
        BState.s1.eventToState.put(BEvent.e1,BState.s2);
        InnerStateMachine<AState,AEvent,ParentEvents> innerStateMachineA=new InnerStateMachine<AState,AEvent,ParentEvents>(AState.s1);
        innerStateMachineA.stateToParentEvent.put(AState.s2,ParentEvents.e1);
        innerStateMachineA.processEvent(AEvent.e1);
        System.out.println(innerStateMachineA.state());
        InnerStateMachine<BState,BEvent,ParentEvents> innerStateMachineB=new InnerStateMachine<BState,BEvent,ParentEvents>(BState.s1);
        innerStateMachineB.processEvent(BEvent.e1);
        System.out.println(innerStateMachineA.state());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful but I also need to pass the type of events the outer state machine, which are different that inner state machine. So I found myself using three generic types.

Comment: yes. you can add a parent event interface, have the corresponding enum implement it, and add it to the generic information for inner state machine. but do you have one set of these or many? i.e. is there one outer state machine or many? if you just have one, you don't need generics.

Comment: There is one state machine but the problem is that I am working on a base architecture and do not really know which it would be. So I cannot assume a concrete interface. Also the inner one can only be allowed to fire events of itself or outer machine not some other events. I hope you get it. I felt that there was no work around to this other than one more generic type. But then it struck my mind that am I over complicating things.

Comment: i added the parent event. you may see a more simple way after you code some of the state machines.

Answer (score 0):

From your descriptions, it looks to me as though your 3 generic class types are more like attributes of your class.  Generics would be right if, for e.g. your ST class type, you want to use either

```
Enum StateEnum1 { idle, busy }
```

and sometimes you want to use

```
Enum StateEnum2 { Idle, QuiteBusy, VeryBusy }.
```

But if you've only got one Enum in mind for each of your 3 generic class types then generics isn't appropriate.

Comment: I have bounded the state machine to be able to fire only its own types or parent type events. That is why I have used generics.

Comment: I'm not sure what context that you're working in, but to me that sounds a bit fussy.  A simpler design might be to set up enums for all possible types from all possible machines, so that generics aren't necessary.  One advantage of that is that if there are states in common, that your code can recognise that and act appropriately, whereas that's harder with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting wrapping your enum into an interface (with implementation accepting the enum) and then use that type as the generic parameter - from your description the enum's look to belong to a cohesive unit.

Also looks like ST and PEV belong to its own interface - much of it is speculation based on the context of the questions.